# Simple question about ideals and quotient rings

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

This one should be easy, so easy in fact that it should be possible to get the answer by plain googling, if only I could figure out the right terms to google.

Let's say that you have ideals $I_1 \subset I_2$ of a ring $R$. Is it then true that $R/I_2$ is isomorphic to a subring of $R/I_1$?

If so, where can I find a proof?

If not, what counterexample is there to offer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Hint:** take $I_1=0$, what happens then?

Comment: Ah! You're saying that if the statement above were true, then it would necessarily have to follow that for any ring $R$ and any ideal $I<R$, $R/I$ would have to be isomorphic to some subring of $R$. This, of course, is not the case, and so the statement must be false! Thanks you! :)

Comment: $I \subset J$ means $R/J = (R/I) /  J$ is a quotient of $R/I$ and $S$ a subring of $R$ means $S/(I\cap S)$ is a subring of $R/I$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ring $R/I_2$ is a *quotient* of $R/I_1$, but is not a subring in general. Take for instance $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $I_1 = 0$ and $I_2 = 2\Bbb{Z}$. Then $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is not isomorphic to any subring of $\Bbb{Z}$.